# How does random number generation ensure reproducibility?

Tags: matlab, random

While reading about [Transfer Learning with MATLab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/transfer-learning-using-convolutional-neural-networks.html) I came across a piece of code which says...

```
rng(2016) % For reproducibility
convnet = trainNetwork(trainDigitData,layers,options);
```

...before training the network so that the results can be reproduced exactly as given in the example by anyone who tries that code. I would like to know how generating a pseudo-random number using `rng(seed_value)` function can help with reproduciblity of the entire range of results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not random number generation, the random number generator *seed*.

There is no such things as random numbers, just pseudo-random numbers, numbers that behave almost as random, generally arising from some complex mathematical function, function that usually requires an initial value. Often, computers get this initial value from the time register in the microchip in your PC, thus "ensuring" randomness.

However, if you have an algorithm that is based in random numbers (e.g. a NN), reproducibility may be a problem when you want to share your results. Someone that re-runs your code will be ensured to get different results, as randomness is part of the algorithm. But, you can tell the random number generator to instead of starting from a seed taken randomly, to start from a fixed seed. That will ensure that while the numbers generated are random between themseves, they are the same each time (e.g. `[3 84 12 21 43 6]` could be the random output, but ti will always be the same).

By setting a seed for your NN, you ensure that for the same data, it will output the same result, thus you can make your code "reproducible", i.e. someone else can run your code and get EXACTLY the same results.

As a test I suggest you try the following:

```
rand(1,10)
rand(1,10)
```

and then try

```
rng(42)
rand(1,10)
rng(42)
rand(1,10)
```

---

[Wikipedia for Pseudo-random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)

Answer (score 1):

Because some times is good to use the same random numbers, this is what matlab [says](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/generate-random-numbers-that-are-repeatable.html) about that

> Set the seed and generator type together when you want to:
>
> ```
> Ensure that the behavior of code you write today returns the same results when you run that code in a future MATLAB® release.
>
> Ensure that the behavior of code you wrote in a previous MATLAB release returns the same results using the current release.
>
> Repeat random numbers in your code after running someone else's random number code
> ```

this is te point of repating the seed, and generate the same random numbers. matlab points it out in two good articles one for [repeating numbers](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/generate-random-numbers-that-are-repeatable.html) and one for [different numbers](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/generate-random-numbers-that-are-different.html)

Answer (score 1):

You dont want to start with weights all equal zeros, so in the initializing stage you give the weights some random value. There maybe other random values involved in searching for minimum later in the learning process, or in the way you feed your data.
So the real input to all neural network learning process is your data and the random number generator. 
If they are the same, than all going to be the same.
And 'rng' command put the random number generator in predefined state so it will generate same sequence of number.

Answer (score 1):

anquegi's answer, pretty much answers your question, so this post is just to elaborate a bit more.

Whenever you ask for a random number, what MATLAB really does, is that it generates a pseudo random number, which has distribution U(0,1) (that is the uniform on [0,1]) This is done via some deterministic formula, typically something like, see [Linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator):

```
X_{n+1} = (a X_{n} + b) mod M
```

then a uniform number is obtained by U = X_{n+1}/M.

There is, however, a problem, If you want X_{1}, then you need X_{0}. You need to initialise the generator, this is the seed. This also means that once X_{0} is specified you will draw the same random numbers, every time. Try open a new MATLAB instance, run `randn`, close MATLAB, open it again and run `randn` again. It will be the same number. That is because MATLAB always uses the same seed whenever it is opened.

So what you do with `rng(2016)` is that you "reset" the generator, and put X_{0} = 2016, such that you now know all numbers that you ask for, and thus reproduce the results.